# Simultaneously diagonalizable linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, diagonalization

I am working on the below problem:

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are linear transformations from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to itself, each having $n$ distinct real eigenvalues. Show that $A$ and $B$ are simultaneously diagonalizable.

Here are my thoughts so far:

First, every linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to itself corresponds to an $n \times n$ matrix with entries in $\mathbb{R}$. Thus, I will proceed with matrix language. Two $n \times n$ matrices $A,B$ are simultaneously diagonalizable if there is a nonsingular matrix $S$ such that $S^{-1}AS$, $S^{-1}BS$ are diagonal matrices.

Further, it's not too difficult to show that the $A,B$ given in the problem are diagonalizable, since the characteristic polynomial (and therefore, the minimal polynomial) will split as a product of distinct linear factors over $\mathbb{R}$. Thus, I believe that my problem reduces down to showing that $A$ and $B$ share the same eigenvectors. This is where I'm not sure how to proceed.

There is a variation of this problem that deals with commuting matrices $A,B$, but we're not offered that luxury here.

How can I show that $A$ and $B$ have the same eigenvectors ? To this point, could there be a typo -- that is, $A$ and $B$ should both have the *same* $n$ distinct eigenvalues in order to prove the result? Would that help me ?

This is a problem on an old Algebra preliminary exam from my department that I was working on.

Thanks!

Comment: This is false. Two transformations are [simultaneously diagonalizable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix#Simultaneous_diagonalization) iff they commute. That they commute easily follows from having a common eigenbasis (their matrices in it are diagonal, and hence commute). If they do not commute having the same eigenvalues makes no difference. This is why [non-commuting observables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_set_of_commuting_observables) in quantum mechanics are not simultaneously measurable.

Comment: @Conifold Okay, I see. Thanks. So, the statement of the problem requires a bit more information, correct ? Meaning, it should tell me that they commute, for example? I was suspicious of the problm for the same reasons -- saying they both have distinct eigenvalues doesn't mean they commute, and all simultaneously diagonalizable transformations must commute. It seems there should be more information given.

Comment: Maybe it asked to prove or disprove, or maybe it was mistyped and it is given that they commute.

Comment: @Conifold Okay. Do you agree with the assessment I made above that the two transformations are diagonalizable only if they share the same eigenvectors ?

Comment: Sure, if they are simultaneously diagonalized the basis must consist of common eigenvectors.